# Uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\sin{{1} \over {n}}\right) x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

$f_n(x)=\left(\sin{{1} \over {n}}\right) x^n$

pointwise convergence: $|f_n(x)|=\left(\sin{{1} \over {n}}\right) |x|^n \sim {{|x|^n}\over{n}}$ for $n \rightarrow +\infty$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}{{|x|^n}\over{n}}$ is a power series and it converges in $E=[-1,1)$

uniform convergence: I calculate sup$_E|f_n(x)|=f_n(1)$ so there isn't unif. convergence in E. Can I have convergence in a subset of E?

If I consider interval $E=[a,b], -1<a<b<1$, $\sup_E|f_n(x)|=\max\left\{\sin{{1} \over {n}}|a|^n,\sin{{1} \over {n}}|b|^n\right\}$, general term of convergent series so there is uniform convergence in $[a,b]$?

Comment: it converges in $(-1,1)$ not $[-1,1)$

Comment: for $x=-1$ is not Leibniz true?

Comment: For $x = -1$ it's just the harmonic serie which diverges

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (sin{{1} \over {n}}) (-1)^n$ is a Leibniz series so I have pointwise convergence in $x=-1$

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sin(1/n))(-1)^n \approx -0.551$.

Comment: Ohhh, mybad I thought you serie was $\sin(\frac{1}{n}) \mid x \mid^n$...

Answer (score 4):

The series converges uniformly on any compact interval $[-1,a] \subset [-1,1)$ with $-1$ as the left endpoint by the Dirichlet test.

Note that $\sin \frac{1}{n} \searrow 0$ monotonically and $\sum_{n = 1}^m x^n$ is uniformly bounded for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in [-1,a]$ with

$$\left|\sum_{n = 1}^m x^n \right| \leqslant \max(1,|a|/(1-|a|)$$

However even though the series converges pointwise for each $x \in [-1,1)$ the convergence is not uniform on any interval $(a,1)$.  We can take $a = 0$ with no loss of generality to prove this non-uniform convergence.

Note that 
$$\sup_{x \in (0,1)} \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}x^k \sin \frac{1}{k}\right| > \sup_{x \in (0,1)} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x^k \sin \frac{1}{k} \\>  \sup_{x \in (0,1)} nx^{2n}\sin \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin \frac{1}{2n}}{\frac{1}{2n}}$$

Since the RHS converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$ the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence is violated.

Comment: I think you can change the RHS of the last inequality to $|a|/(1-|a|)$ discarding the max.

Comment: So it doesn't converge on the whole $[-1, 1)$.  Since I did a big mistake I am wondering how to prove uniform convergence on an open set $(a,b)$ ? If the serie doesn't converge pointwise at the endpoint $a$ and $b$, I don't see a general strategy to prove uniform convergence... Since uniform convergence is a global property, when the interval is open it seems hard to prove uniform convergence

Comment: @Thinking: What exactly is the question now? On a compact interval $[a,b] \subset (-1,1)$ it is easy to see uniform convergence by the Weierstrass test.  The Dirichlet test extends it to $[-1,b]$.

Comment: @RRL Sorry, but maybe I should make a post to ask this. Here I am not talking about the serie of the OP. If we have a sequence of $f_n : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $(a,b)$ but doesn't converge pointwise on the endpoints (ie. not on $a$, not on $b$). Then I am wondering what are the strategy to prove that $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly ? We can't use the $M$-test since $\sum f_n$ don't converge on $a$ and $b$... I mean the fact that uniforme convergence is a global property makes it hard since $(a,b)$ is an open set. So how to do when dealing with this ?

Comment: @Thinking: I finished this problem by showing you why it fails to converge on an interval $[a,1)$. To address your general question you would first need to understand what has been shown here.  You are also mixing generalities with specific aspects of this problem.  " We can't use the M-test since $\sum f_n$ doesn't ...".  And apparently the OP is not even interested in what has transpired here!

Comment: @irchans: What if $a = 1/3$? Then $|a|/(1- |a|) = 1/2$ which is not the bound needed for $x = -1$.  We need a uniform bound for the Dirichlet test.

Comment: @RRL Ok (+1). My question wasn't clear but I'll ask this in an other post.

Comment: @Thinking: Good idea.

Comment: @RRL  You are right !!   :)

Comment: Happy New Year RRL (Is it to late to say that?)!  I hadn't seen your post as I was writing mine.  They are close in their approaches and so I am happy to delete mine unless you think it is a useful supplement.

Comment: @MarkViola: Happy New Year — although it seems to be going fast. I would say your answer is sufficiently different and it’s not really something I would ever be concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac1n\right)x^n$ fails to converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$.  To see this, we can write

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac1n\right)x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sin\left(\frac1n\right)-\frac1n\right)x^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n\tag1$$

The first series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ converges uniformly on $[-1,1]$ since the term $\sin\left(\frac1n\right)-\frac1n=O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$.  Therefore, it is enough to show that the second series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ fails to converge on $(-1,1)$.

---

To negate the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}=-\log(1-x)$ on $(-1,1)$, we choose $\varepsilon=\frac18\log(2)$.  Then, we have for any $N\ge1$ and $x=1-\frac1{N+1}\in(0,1)$

$$\begin{align}
\left|-\log(1-x)-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{x^n}{n}\right|=&\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{x^n}{n}\right|\\\\
&=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}\\\\
&\ge \sum_{n=N+1}^{2N+1} \frac{x^n}{n}\\\\
&\ge \left(1-\frac1{N+1}\right)^{2N+1}\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N+1}\frac1n\\\\
&\ge \left(1-\frac1{N+1}\right)^{2N+1}\log(2)\\\\
&\ge \frac18\log(2)\\\\
&=\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

And hence the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ converges on $[-1,1)$ but fails to converge uniformly on $[-1,1)$.